# Proving $\sum_{1}^{n} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2n}{2i-1}\right\rceil=2n -1 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2n}{2i-1}\right\rceil=2n -1 $$ where $ \lceil\cdot\rceil$ denotes the ceiling function.

My method: one way would be observe each part of the summation is telling numbers of form $2^\alpha k$ where $k$ is any odd number (from the list of numbers from $2$ to $2n$).

But I would like to know whether there is an algebraic proof, or maybe some bit of number theory that will help solve it.

Comment: Is this true?  If $n=2$ the left hand is $\big \lfloor \log_2 \frac {4}{1}\big \rfloor + \big \lfloor \log_2 \frac {4}{3}\big \rfloor=2$ not $3$.

Comment: Oh i am sorry i am editing it a bit

Comment: Now i think least integer function should rectify it @lulu

Comment: Oh, you are using the ceiling function?  That's very non-standard notation.  You used the old notation for the floor function.  I suggest editing to use the standard notation for the ceiling function, \lceil $\cdots$ \rceil

Comment: Or you might be having a better way of getting the intuition of the above proof i gave to make the expression right

Comment: Sure @lulu ....

Comment: I edited it to improve the notation, but I might have stomped on your notation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, please ignore my comment.

Comment: Okay i see  @Dmitry

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cleft%5Clceil%5Clog_%7B2%7D%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2i-1%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%3Dn-1%24&p=1), I found the more general [Does $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\lceil \log_2\frac{N}{i}\rceil$ have a closed form?](/q/847104), and the somewhat similar [How to show $n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor{\log_2\frac{2n-1}{2k-1}}\right\rfloor$ for every natural number $n$.](/q/3077073).

Comment: Nice thanks for those @JohnOmielan

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by induction. The first observation is:
$$\left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2n}{2i-1}\right\rceil = 1 + \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{n}{2i-1}\right\rceil$$

So it suffices to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{n}{2i-1}\right\rceil = n-1$. The next observation is that the latter half of the sum is zero (when $2i - 1 > n$, we have $\frac{n}{2i-1} \in (\frac 12, 1)$). Formally:

**$n=2k$:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k}{2i-1}\right\rceil = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k}{2i-1}\right\rceil + 0,$$

which by induction hypothesis is $2k-1 = n - 1$.

**$n=2k + 1$:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k + 1}{2i-1}\right\rceil = \sum_{i=1}^{k + 1} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k + 1}{2i-1}\right\rceil + 0 = 
1 + \sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k + 1}{2i-1}\right\rceil.$$

We want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k + 1}{2i-1}\right\rceil = (n - 1) - 1 = 2k$.
By the induction hypothesis, we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k}{2i-1}\right\rceil = 2k - 1$.
Let's compare them term by term, i.e. $\left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k}{2i-1}\right\rceil$ vs $\left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k + 1}{2i-1}\right\rceil$.

Let's fix $i$, and let $\ell$ be the smallest integer such that $2^\ell \ge \frac{2k}{2i-1}$.
When is it not the case that $2^\ell \ge \frac{2k + 1}{2i - 1}$? It happens iff $\frac{2k}{2i - 1}$ is a power of two.
This happens for exactly on term: for $i$ such that $2k = (2i - 1) \cdot 2^t$ for some $t$.
Hence,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k + 1}{2i-1}\right\rceil = 1 +\sum_{i=1}^k \left\lceil\log_{2}\frac{2k}{2i-1}\right\rceil = 2k$$